# Creating tickets in Zendesk

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I am new to Zendesk, but what I want is for my app to be able to create tickets in Zendesk. Basically, when a user does something in my web application, my backend application creates a ticket for a Support to look at the issue and resolve it.

Looking at the Zendesk API for creating tickets, it seems that it asks for agent username and password, but there is no agent, just a machine that is creating those tickets. So my question here is, should I use some different approach to this problem, or should I work around by creating a user for the machine with imaginary email address so that I can authenticate?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you should use the "request" endpoint, instead of the "ticket". 
Here is an example that may help:

```
fetch('https://SUBDOMAIN.zendesk.com/api/v2/requests.json', {
method: 'post',headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'  },
body: JSON.stringify({"request": {"requester": {"name": "Anonymous customer"}, "subject": "Vlad test", "comment": {"body": "Here goes a ticket body"
}}})
}).then(res=>res.json()).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: any idea How I can mention which group should receive the ticket. say there are three groups 'dispute', 'product', 'support', how can i create a ticket for 'product' group when the user selects 'product' option so that the ticket only shows up in the panel of agents on 'product' group only on zendesk. @wladan

Comment: that can be done with Zendesk Triggers. 
conditions: new ticket is created,
ticket type == product;

Actions: Group is ..eg Product.